# Is it possible to link to another website, have it open in a new tab, and then scroll to a div on that website?

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

For example

`<a href="https://amazon.com" target="_blank"> Go to amazon and scroll to footer </a>`

When you click that not only does it open amazon in a new tab but it scrolls automatically to the footer when it opens.

Comment: You can add a fragment to the URL: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment

Comment: Yes, if that div have unique id that you can refer to. 
For example on the amazon.com the footer id is `navFooter` so your link will look like this: 
`<a href="https://amazon.com#navFooter" ... </a>`

Comment: I don't think you can smooth scroll to the element if that is your goal.

Comment: @dziku86 Doesn't matter if its a smooth scroll I was just curious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being what dziku86 commented.

"Yes, if that div have unique id that you can refer to. For example on the amazon.com the footer id is navFooter so your link will look like this:  <a href="https://amazon.com#navFooter" ... "